# How do you troubleshoot a node-app app with haproxy?

Tags: juju, maas, nodejs

I've got what appears to be an almost-functioning install of my node app within an Ubuntu Trusty MAAS rig with Juju on a private network (which doesn't need to be published).  I'm using juju-gui so was able to export this bundle.yaml file content:

```
series: trusty
services: 
  keystone: 
    charm: "cs:trusty/keystone-29"
    num_units: 1
    options: 
      "admin-password": "redacted"
    to: 
      - "lxc:"
  ntp: 
    charm: "cs:trusty/ntp-11"
  mongodb: 
    charm: "cs:trusty/mongodb-26"
    num_units: 1
    to: 
      - "lxc:"
  docs: 
    charm: "cs:~justin-fathomdb/trusty/node-app-0"
    num_units: 1
    options: 
      app_name: docs
      app_url: "http://github.com/redacted/redacted.git"
    to: 
      - "0"
  haproxy: 
    charm: "cs:trusty/haproxy-13"
    num_units: 1
    to: 
      - "1"
relations: 
  - - "ntp:juju-info"
    - "keystone:juju-info"
  - - "docs:mongodb"
    - "mongodb:database"
  - - "docs:website"
    - "haproxy:reverseproxy"
machines: 
  "0": 
    series: trusty
    constraints: "arch=amd64 cpu-cores=2 mem=2048"
  "1": 
    series: trusty
    constraints: "arch=amd64 cpu-cores=2 mem=4096"
  undefined: 
    series: trusty
    constraints: "arch=amd64 cpu-cores=2 mem=4096"
```

Looks like haproxy is deployed successfully to node delta.maas and juju status shows that it's on port 80.  I can ssh into this node and see that /var/log/juju/unit-haproxy-2.log seems to be happy.  The file /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg indicates that it knows about the docs node:

```
backend haproxy_service
  balance leastconn
  cookie SRVNAME insert
  server docs-2-8000 10.100.100.10:8000 maxconn 100 cookie S0 check
```

Looks like docs (the node-app) is deployed to node alpha.maas and juju status shows that it's on port 8000.  I can ssh into this node and see that /var/log/juju/unit-docs-2.log seems to be happy.  It brought in the github image, ran npm install, found mongodb.  Running a "ps aux|grep node" on this node yields:

```
ubuntu   22954  0.0  0.4 657432  9600 ?        Rsl  21:28   0:00 node ./bin/www
```

Running "netstat -nat|grep LISTEN" however seems to indicate that node isn't bound:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Per the documentation I'm using a Procfile in the application's root:

```
web: node ./bin/www
```

...and the bin/www file begins with this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('docs:server');
var http = require('http');
var config = require('../config/config');
var port = normalizePort(process.env.port);
app.set('port', process.env.port);
...
```

What's annoying is that the config-changed hook on the node-app Juju charms pretty much always fails at the github step, pretending like it can't find it.  Fortunately, the install hooks succeeds, however.  So it feels like I'll need to remove-unit/add-unit in order to make any changes to the app itself even to troubleshoot this.

Trying the haproxy IP address results in a 503 Service Unavailable error.  Trying the 8000 port from a browser for the docs node itself yields no answer since--as I noted before--it's not listening to anything.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the app's config/config.js file includes:  
module.exports = config = {
  "name" : "docs"
  ,"listen_port" : 8000
  ,"mongo_host" : "localhost"
  ,"mongo_port" : 27017
}